# Websocket connection issues encountered when using fabric8 kubernetes-client 6.7.2 with IPv6?

Tags: kubernetes, watch, fabric8-kubernetes-client

We are attempting to utilize the Kubernetes watch functionality using fabric8 kubernetes-client 6.7.2. While it successfully establishes a websocket connection in IPv4, but the websocket connection is not opening in IPv6.

Have anyone encountered this issue with the fabric8 kubernetes-client 6.7.2 where the websocket connection is not being opened in IPv6? If so, could you please provide your insights or suggestions on how to resolve it?

I have developed a simple standalone client to invoke the Kubernetes watch functionality using fabric8 kubernetes-client 6.7.2. It functions correctly in an IPv4 environment, but unfortunately, it fails to establish websocket connections in an IPv6 setting.

Comment: Just a question, why do you need IPv6?

Comment: this is one of our customer usecase